# restFB - can't post to page - only to my wall

Tags: facebook, post, restfb

I created a Facebook app that I will use to programatically post information to Facebook.  I've got it working so that I can post to my wall, but not the page I'd like it to go to (for which I am 1 of 2 administrators).

this posts to my page just fine:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("<ACCESS_TOKEN>"); 
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("<MY_FB_NAME>/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "Testing..."));
```

but if I try to post the page, I get an error:

com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

The  code is the same, except I replace my name with the page's ID:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("<ACCESS_TOKEN>"); 
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("<THE_PAGE_ID>/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "Testing..."));
```

The app is listed as one of the apps for the page.

Thanks for any help with this,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct (`publish_stream`) [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)?

You'll need that to post as the user to places other than their own profile.

Comment: I don't think so, the code is just those 2 lines.  I'll look into that, but if you can't point me in the right direction on setting that permission, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: read the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs - it explains all the auth flows

Comment: What do you mean 'as the app'?

Comment: igy - i may be confusing things due to my lack of knowledge - it's just the message will say "via <appname>" under the message...

Comment: That's present on all posts made by your app - it'll be 'from' the person who authorised your app (whose access token you're using) and 'via' the app itself

Comment: OK, I got it to work - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/ was very helpful